# When to use POJOs to define entities in google appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google Appengine. While learning the basics of Google Datastore, I came across the concepts on Entities and saw 2 ways of defining and storing them.

One is to use POJOs with annotations to define entities and register them in Objectify before storing them.

```
@Entity
Class Employee{
    @Id
    private long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    // add constructors and getters
}
```

Another one is to just use the Entity() constructor to define entity and later set the properties:

```
Entity employee = new Entity("Employee");
employee.setProperty("firstName", "Antonio");
employee.setProperty("lastName", "Salieri");
```

My question is which way should be used when to describe entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **low level API** (your second example) allows you to take advantage of the NonSQL nature of the datastore, as objects aren't really stored in tables you could have entities of the same type with different attributes. Which is great if you need that, but it really leaves you to implement a lot of their logic yourself.

**Objectify** on the other end ( definitively recommended over JDO and JPA!) allows you to easily map your objects to datastore entities and provides most of the querying/marshalling logic out of the box.

> My question is which way should be used when to describe entities?

It really depends on your project's requirements but in my experience 99% of the times you get everything you need from objectify. It has been designed specifically for the GAE and it's datastore, it's interface it's pretty clean and straight to the point. If you are new to GAE and would like to ease into the concepts you should go for Objectify, you'll be saving yourself from a world of pain :)

Answer (score 2):

Objectify reduces the amount of boiler-plate code and does many useful things under the hood.

Low-level datastore API, the second option that you describe, requires more boiler-plate but gives you more control and better performance, if you know how to use it.

The choice depends on what you know better and the details of a project that you plan to implement.